# Lambda reading from dynamod DB and dumping data to SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a application, that writes data to DynamoDB table. I have to read this data from DynamoDB perform some other business logic on it and store the resulting data in MySQL.

I was thinking of using a lambda function to read data from DynamoDB and putting it to MySql. The only concern I am having is what if the write to SQL fails and I end up with missing data records.

Is there a way I can achieve atomicity between the two. Any pointers.

Comment: you would like to use [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/), first insert id into [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/), once data inserted into MySQL then you can delete id from  [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)

Comment: But SQS doesn't trigger a lambda

Comment: I was thinking of using Spring Transacation management to make these atomic, but am not sure about that.

Comment: you could also look into Kinesis streams (downside being a minimum of about $12/mon for a stream) - it can trigger a lambda and will keep retrying (for up to 7 days) if the lambda throws an error